# (C) How to fill a 2D array with an input that's a full N x N matrix?

Tags: c, arrays, matrix, 2d

I'm trying to make a 2D array of size N x N that is going to be filled with a matrix input.

```
printf("Enter the %d x %d matrix: \n", length, length);

for (m = 0; m < length; m++) {
    for (n = 0; n < lenth; n++) {
        scanf("%d", &array[m][n]);
    }
}
```

The input will be a full N x N array. Such as:

```
0  10 40
10 0 5
40 5 0
```

Comment: What do you want ? Make it more clear!

Comment: What is the problem, then?!

Comment: printf() out m and n just before the scanf, (with a \n).  This is called debugging.  You could, instead, use an actual debugger....

Comment: `int arr[length][length];`?  Or maybe `int (*arr)[length] = malloc(length * sizeof(*arr));`?